# Will upgrading to Rails 5 cause issues with my current rails 4.x project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have built my site using rails 4.2, and I want to upgrade to rails 5 so I can use the ActionCable to build a live chat inside my website.

Will doing so cause any problems with my current project? Will I need to start the project from scratch upon upgrading?

Answer (score 1):

I read this great article on upgrading from 4.2 -> 5. It goes through pretty much all the issues that could be encountered. Probably best to read through this than me explaining: http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2015/12/upgrading-to-ruby-on-rails-5-0-from-rails-4-2-application-use-case/